# Multiple attachments in sent folder using Imap_Append in PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I am using below code to add multiple attachments to a mail message in sent folder using IMAP_APPEND. In the sent folder I am getting only one attachment not other.. can anyone suggest what is the issue with this??

```
    if ($mbox=imap_open( $authhost, $user, $pass)) 
        { 

            $dmy=date("d-M-Y H:i:s"); 
            $boundary = "------=" . md5(uniqid(rand()));
            $msg .= "From: ".$from[0]."\r\n" 
                . "To: ".$recipients[$key][0]."\r\n" 
                . "CC: ".$ccList."\r\n" 
                . "Date: $dmy\r\n" 
                . "Subject: $subject\r\n"                   
                . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" 
                . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n" 
                . "\r\n\r\n" 
                . "--$boundary\r\n" 
                . "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n\tcharset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\r\n" 
                . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit \r\n" 
                . "\r\n\r\n" 
                . $body . "\r\n" 
                . "\r\n\r\n" 
                . "--$boundary\r\n" 
                . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 


                foreach($attachment as $attchURL){
                    $files = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/attachments/" . $attchURL;
                    $filename = substr($attchURL, strrpos($attchURL,"/")+1);
                    $ouv=fopen ("$files", "rb");$lir=fread ($ouv, filesize ("$files"));
                    fclose($ouv);
                    $attachments = chunk_split(base64_encode($lir));                        
                    $msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\r\n" ;                     
                    $msg .=  "\r\n" . $attachments . "\r\n"; 
                }
                $msg .= "\r\n\r\n\r\n" 
                . "--$boundary--\r\n\r\n"; 

            imap_append($mbox,$authhost,($msg)); 
            imap_close($mbox); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($mbox=imap_open( $authhost, $user, $pass)) 
    { 

        $dmy=date("d-M-Y H:i:s"); 
        $boundary = "------=" . md5(uniqid(rand()));
        $msg .= "From: ".$from[0]."\r\n" 
            . "To: ".$recipients[$key][0]."\r\n" 
            . "CC: ".$ccList."\r\n" 
            . "Date: $dmy\r\n" 
            . "Subject: $subject\r\n"                   
            . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" 
            . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n" 
            . "\r\n\r\n" 
            . "--$boundary\r\n" 
            . "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n\tcharset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\r\n" 
            . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit \r\n" 
            . "\r\n\r\n" 
            . $body . "\r\n" 
            . "\r\n\r\n"; 


            foreach($attachment as $attchURL){
                $files = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/attachments/" . $attchURL;
                $filename = substr($attchURL, strrpos($attchURL,"/")+1);
                $ouv=fopen ("$files", "rb");$lir=fread ($ouv, filesize ("$files"));
                fclose($ouv);
                $attachments = chunk_split(base64_encode($lir));                        


                $msg .=  "--$boundary\r\n" 
                $msg .=  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
                $msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\r\n" ;                     
                $msg .=  "\r\n" . $attachments . "\r\n"; 
            }
            $msg .= "\r\n\r\n\r\n" 
            . "--$boundary--\r\n\r\n"; 

        imap_append($mbox,$authhost,($msg)); 
        imap_close($mbox); 
    }
```

Comment: It is always preferable to include an explanation to your code